# Django internalization error in utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, django

I am having the following error while executing the following command in django:

django-admin makemessages -l en

the error is this string:           Please specify the source encoding through --from-code or through a comment
          as specified in http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html.

the settings.py configurations is this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = [
('en', 'English'),
('ru', 'Russian'),
]  

USE_I18N = True 

LOCALE_PATHS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]
```

My django version is 2.1 and I am using pyCharm on Ubuntu 18.04. I did some research I found out that there is bug but it was corrected after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout if your project virtual environment folder, is in the root directory of your project like:

```
project
  |
  |----project
  |----app1
  |----app2
  ...
  |----project_env
  |----manage.py
```

if so, use this command:

```
django-admin makemessages -l en -i project_env
```

the problem is when you run `makemessages` command it will look in all of sub directories for messages, so the libraries in site-packages cause this error. by using `-i` you can ignore environment folder.

## as a recommendation!

actually that would be better to not include environment folder in project root folder, instead you can add a `requirements.txt` file and add all project dependencies to it. so next time after activating a new virtual environment you can easily reinstall project dependencies with this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

this [python virtual environment document](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id1) would be helpful.

Comment: Well, It worked but I have a question. What was the problem? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @MajorMail your welcome, may you please mark answer as accepted? i have updated the answer.

Comment: @mujad happy to hear that! ;)